# Displaytag: showing incorrect number of items

Tags: java, jsp, displaytag

I have a problem showing a list of 10 items in my table.
At page #1,#3,#4,#5... i can see 10 items, page #2 only show one result. I print the content of my list object in every page, and this list contains 10 items. 
What is wrong with page #2?

[image]

**EDIT**

This list was working well. I just changed the way to get the data from the database, but, the result of this List has the expected values as you can see int the previous image. This behaviour occurs when i go to page #2, I can se more than 250 pages, but page #2 is missing something...

JSP Code:

```
    <display:table 
                id="tableId"
                summary="Results"
                name="myList" 
                pagesize="10"
                requestURI="" 
                defaultsort="1" 
                defaultorder="ascending" 
                sort="external"
                export="true" 
                cellpadding="0" 
                cellspacing="0" 
                partialList="true"

                size='<%=request.getAttribute("totalSize")%>'
                decorator="com.zyz.decorators.TableWrapper">
                <display:setProperty name="css.tr.even" value="null" />
                <display:setProperty name="css.tr.odd"  value="odd" />
                <display:column class="darkTD TH17">
                    <center>
                    <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkItem()" id="checkDelList" name="checkDelList" value="${tableId.id}"/></center> 
                    <input type="hidden" idd="__checkbox_checkDelList" name="__checkbox_checkDelList"/>
                    </center>
                </display:column>               

                <display:column property="state" titleKey="xyz.state" sortable="true"
/></display:table>
```

Comment: Ass some code of the jsp page please

Comment: I can post java code (i'm using Strut2, Spring and hibernate), but as i say in my question, the value of "myList" are the same before&after the change i made.

Comment: It seems you use custom server side pagination but we don't know how you implemented it. Probably you have something wrong there.

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm using values of displaytag to extract the correct rows from my database (page number, order and column sort) using rownum field (Oracle database). The values are correct, but not what i see on the html. When i return the result of my query, i can see inside this List<T> 10 objects, but displaytag only shows one.

Comment: @Alex you are right, i was getting wrong the number of the elements.